# DataTable is sorted after selecting from Excel

Tags: oledb, import-from-excel

When i select records from excelsheet the datatable is sorted.
I want the records in same sequence as excelsheet, why is the datatable sorted.

OleDbCommand objCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT distinct * FROM [" + strSheet + "]", objXConn);

OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(objCommand);

objAdapter.Fill(dtEx);

Answer (score 0):

It was taking the first column datatype as Numeric. i added the IMEX=1 in extended properties, now since the column is treated as string the data is not sorted anymore.

Thanks